# How can I update mapped inner arrays in Knockout without updating the number of array objects in the main array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, mapping

I'm working on a stock watcher site that automatically updates stock prices through AJAX. With this I've decided to use knockout.js to be able to automatically update the UI of the site when the variable has been updated.

I have the following sample JSON object for my initial list (on load of the webpage), which is being pulled from my database to ensure that all companies gets pulled. For this example I have 4 companies as such:

```
var companiesData = 
[
  {  
     "Date":"2013-04-19",
     "company":"AAA", 
     "close":1.68,
     "open":1.8
  },
  {  
     "Date":"2013-04-19",
     "company":"BBB", 
     "close":13.68,
     "open":12.8
  },
  {  
     "Date":"2013-04-19",
     "company":"CCC", 
     "close":21.68,
     "open":21.6
  },
  {  
     "Date":"2013-04-19",
     "company":"DDD", 
     "close":19.68,
     "open":17.8
  }
]
```

I created an observableArray object and assigned it to the viewModel as such:

```
var viewModel = {
    companies = ko.observableArray(companiesData)
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I then have an Ajax function that pulls updated ticker data, which contains only those companies that have updated, and the data that have been updated. Please note that I'm using a third party API to pull the updated data so I don't have control over the format. Let's say only companies AAA and BBB got updated:

```
var updatedCompaniesData = 
[
  {  
     "company":"AAA", 
     "close":1.90
  },
  {  
     "company":"BBB", 
     "close":15.08
  }
]
```

When I update the observableArray with the updatedCompanies, the whole observableArray gets replaced with the updatedCompanies, returning only 2 instead of 4, and missing the properties. I've read in the documentation that

### An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects

And so I've learned that since I only need to update specific companies that has new data, but need retain the old companies that have not been updated, I need to make each property of each company an observable. So I used the mapping plugin for this, and assigned a key property to my array. With this, KO will only look for the key and update the other properties (open, close, Date) instead of deleting the company and re-adding the updated one. I've also used its create method to add ko.computed functions in each array.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(companiesData, {
    key: function(comp) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(comp.company);
},
create: function(comp) {
    return new Company(comp.data);
}
}, viewModel.companies);
```

My question is, how can I update the properties (just the price, open, close) of each company, but not the observableArray? Updating the observableArray itself 'reloads' the number of companies. What will be the 'knockout' way of doing it?

I have found the update option of but I'm not sure how to use it in this scenario, given that I don't have array names in my JSON object.

[From Knockout Mapping Plugin Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

```
var mapping = {
'name': {
    update: function(options) {
        return options.data + 'foo!';
        }
    }
}
```

Another question would be, do I have to use an observableArray if I don't intend to modify the number of companies, but just intend to update each company's property in that array?

Comment: Paul was able to nail the answer! I didn't need to use the Key attribute, just the Create for initially mapping the variables. :) As for the update, the answer below already gives the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, scrap that last answer. Having gone through the code in the mapping plugin itself, it's just not designed to update individual items in an observable array, as far as I can tell, it will delete any array items that are not in the updated data.

So, given that, you don't want to use the mapping plugin to update the data, just use a simple for each loop:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(updatedCompaniesData, function (updatedCompany) {
    var company = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.companies(), function (item) {
        return item.Name() === updatedCompany.company;
    });

    if (company) {
        company.ClosingPrice(updatedCompany.close);
    }
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzanotti/w2cJ4/7/).

Comment: Thanks Paul! Is there really a double ': :' or just one? Either case I tried it, it didn't work. I have two ajax calls, the initial list comes from my DB and the subsequent list comes from a 3rd party. For both calls I used this code. I'm not sure how to update the data, do I use the exact code (with the ko.mapping.fromJS + key) when updating data? Also, with this code, will I be able to NOT touch the companies observableArray but just its specific properties?

Comment: Ok, had to break out a jsFiddle, but I think I've got it.

Comment: You did, thanks a lot! I've been asking around for a solution to this for days now. I'm so glad you were able to solve it!